# Visual Studio debugging performance issue with symbols

Tags: performance, debugging, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5, symbols

We are using Visual Studio 2012 and .net 4.5, running locally on local IIS7

When debugging Visual Studio launches quickly, to the designated start page. On this page we have a quick link for each customer to log in as a developer into our one application for this customer.

When clicking this link, sometimes it takes a couple of seconds to log in, sometimes several minutes.

When it takes several minutes, it's not executing our code that takes up that time, it's something else.

I tried pausing the application while it's stuck and I get "The call stack contains only external code" and a list like this:

[image]

What could be causing this, how should we go about to find out and solve it?

EDIT:

Output:

'w3wp.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2a7f4adc\44d43685\App_Web_fwznfivy.dll', Symbols loaded.
'w3wp.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2a7f4adc\44d43685\App_Web_yx4yizpa.dll', Symbols loaded.
'w3wp.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2a7f4adc\44d43685\App_Web_wdqdaadj.dll', Symbols loaded.
'w3wp.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2a7f4adc\44d43685\App_Web_wpbhxrdc.dll', Symbols loaded.
'w3wp.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2a7f4adc\44d43685\App_Web_otc4htkm.dll', Symbols loaded.
'w3wp.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2a7f4adc\44d43685\App_Web_cynxmykn.dll', Symbols loaded.
'w3wp.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2a7f4adc\44d43685\App_Web_casx31q0.dll', Symbols loaded.
'w3wp.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2a7f4adc\44d43685\App_Web_4cbmhbc4.dll', Symbols loaded.
'w3wp.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2a7f4adc\44d43685\App_Web_1bu05w0p.dll', Symbols loaded.
'w3wp.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2a7f4adc\44d43685\App_Web_o54kfz1h.dll', Symbols loaded.
'w3wp.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2a7f4adc\44d43685\App_Web_3nzc5gqo.dll', Symbols loaded.
'w3wp.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2a7f4adc\44d43685\App_Web_ea0poktt.dll', Symbols loaded.
'w3wp.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2a7f4adc\44d43685\App_Web_zvgpqz0m.dll', Symbols loaded.
'w3wp.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2a7f4adc\44d43685\App_Web_5wr2m003.dll', Symbols loaded.
'w3wp.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2a7f4adc\44d43685\App_Web_t5ua431x.dll', Symbols loaded.
'w3wp.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2a7f4adc\44d43685\App_Web_3dbfcwsb.dll', Symbols loaded.
'w3wp.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2a7f4adc\44d43685\App_Web_fxdkwpep.dll', Symbols loaded.
'w3wp.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2a7f4adc\44d43685\App_Web_mamfkdlr.dll', Symbols loaded.
'w3wp.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2a7f4adc\44d43685\App_Web_cdpqzfas.dll', Symbols loaded.

Comment: Are you loading symbols from the Microsoft symbol server?

Comment: I recently started caching symbols locally, this sped up the initial startup a bit, however that is not where the problem lies.

Comment: Edited question with output.